# Stop Wordpress pages being overwritten upon plugin update

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a website which to briefly summarise, has a front-end managed by WordPress and which uses a plugin (containing php, html, javascript, images..) as an intermediary to provide data for the front-end by linking to a database.
The trouble is when the plugin is updated, the deployment process is such that everything gets updated including the 'pages'. This means these pages, any additional CSS etc.. have to be re-implemented which isn't ideal.
Is there a recommended practice of protecting these front-end files so that they don't get overwritten when the plugin is updated?
I'm wondering whether there's some kind of archiving facility that could be invoked just before a scheduled plugin update so that the pages can be re-instated when it's safe to go back into the water, so to speak.

Many thanks.

Comment: which is the plugin? do you want to stop the update of the plugin or to stop the update of your frontend files?

Comment: It's a bespoke third party plugin. I want to merely stop the update of the front-end files only. The plugin itself will be periodically updated and this is out of my control.

Comment: are you using a child theme? what's the name of the plugin?

Comment: There is no child theme, no inheritance from a parent theme as such but the plugin does have it's own theme and I need to make amendments to it. What happens is links in the main menu get overwritten with default menu items and page content not dependant on the plugin is also overwritten. So if I add a CSS class to a page which has a corresponding CSS declaration in Additional CSS, it all gets overwritten. Regarding the plugin, I'm not sure whether I'm permitted to disclose it but it is bespoke and not available to anyone to install.

Comment: write to the plugin support, it's your better choice...